# Get Row With Max Date

Tags: sql-server, row-number

I'm attempting to write a query to get the row with the maxdate.

Upon doing research, I found the following query should work:

```
SELECT OrgSeatID, CreateDate, T.ROW
FROM (SELECT OrgSeatID, CreateDate, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY OrgSeatID ORDER BY CreateDate DESC) AS [ROW]
      FROM OrgSeat) AS T
WHERE T.[ROW] = 1
```

However, it's returning all of the rows, it is not ordering the CreateDate DESC as it should, and the ROW column reads 1 for all rows.

Can anyone see what I'm doing wrong with this query?

Comment: Remove the Partition BY clause, just have OVER(ORDER BY CREATE_DATE DESC)

Answer (score 1):

The query you wrote will return the most recently created record **per OrgSeatID**, as per your `PARTITION BY`. So you're getting one row per each OrgSeatID existing in your database, as the `ROW_NUMBER()` window function is creating a partition for each of them and then ordering rows within that partition.

If you want the most recent record of all your records, really the easiest way is to just:

```
SELECT TOP 1 OrgSeatID, CreateDate
  FROM OrgSeat
 ORDER BY CreateDate DESC
```

The equivalent using a window function, although less optimal, would be:

```
SELECT OrgSeatID, CreateDate, T.ROW
  FROM (SELECT OrgSeatID, CreateDate, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY CreateDate DESC) AS [ROW]
          FROM OrgSeat
     ) AS T
 WHERE T.[ROW] = 1
```